# Trying to get my SSIS to continue running if a file doesn't exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

So, I am running SSIS (through VS) and I have two segments that hang me up when my clients don't send in the exact files every day.  I have a task that deletes old files, and then renames the current files to the filename with _OLD at the end of it.

The issue is: If the files that are in there aren't the exact same, it crashes, failing the entire thing.

An example:
A client sends in on Monday files: Names, Addresses, Grades, Schools
The same client, on Tuesday sends in: Names, Addresses, Schools

Since the Grades file doesn't exist, it still gets renamed to Grades_OLD but the SSIS fails.

The scripts are:

```
del Names_OLD.csv
bye
```

This will then go to the Rename Script:

```
ren Names.csv Names_OLD.csv
bye
```

and will then go on to Addresses, to do the same thing.  It is super frustrating that these fail when a single file doesn't exist the next day, and there doesn't seem to be a need for it.

We have two scripts that generate the archive data to process:

```
public void Main()
{
Dts.Variables["ARCHIVEFILE"].Value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Dts.Variables["FTPFILE"].Value.ToString()) + "_OLD" + Path.GetExtension(Dts.Variables["FTPFILE"].Value.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

and

```
public void Main()
{
/*PSFTP_DEL_script.txt
del %1
bye

PSFTP_REN_script.txt
ren %1 %2
bye
*/

var lineOut = String.Empty;
var File1 = Dts.Variables["User::FTPWORKINGDIR"].Value.ToString() + "\\SSIS_PSFTP_DEL_script.txt";
var File2 = Dts.Variables["User::FTPWORKINGDIR"].Value.ToString() + "\\SSIS_PSFTP_REN_script.txt";

lineOut = "del " + Dts.Variables["User::ARCHIVEFILE"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "bye";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(File1, lineOut);

lineOut = "ren " + Dts.Variables["User::FTPFILE"].Value.ToString() + " " + Dts.Variables["User::ARCHIVEFILE"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "bye";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(File2, lineOut);            

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Researching it doesn't really give anything helpful, and kind of just leads me back to where I am right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop on files for each file that can be processed and put all the processing of the file inside it. And do not put any precendence constraints between the foreach loops.

This will process the files that are there an not fail when the others aren't there.

The foreach loop essentially works as a check if the file exists.

This assumes you do not need all the files to properly process them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not checking if the file exists before writing the script:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::ARCHIVEFILE"].Value.ToString())){

    lineOut = "del " + Dts.Variables["User::ARCHIVEFILE"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "bye";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(File1, lineOut);

}

if (Dts.Variables["User::FTPFILE"].Value.ToString())){

    lineOut = "ren " + Dts.Variables["User::FTPFILE"].Value.ToString() + " " + Dts.Variables["User::ARCHIVEFILE"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "bye";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(File2, lineOut);   

}
```

Comment: Not going to lie, because I googled my way through the job that I have here.  I'm not really a Dev, just was trying something new.  Would this simply skip it if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: This will not write a script if no file exists

Comment: Sorry @Hadi I was out of town.  I got an error when I tried saving this over that. [Image to error](https://i.imgur.com/EtNE7Ul.png)